# alternative control block in php doesn't work

Tags: php

I have this code in my html file which is rendered by PHP:

```
<div>
  <?php if($SESSION.userName=='UNSET'):  ?>
     User is not logged in
  <?php else: ?>
     user is logged in: user name is: {{ @SESSION.userName }}
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div> test  {{ @SESSION.userName }} 
</div>
```

The above code generates this output:

```
User is not logged in user is logged in: user name is: a
test a
```

This apparently means that the if statement is not calculated.

What is the problem and how I can fix it? I am new to PHP (just started today!)

Note: logged username is a

## Edit1

The page is rendered using this function from an index.php file:

```
$f3->route(
  'GET @home:/',
  function ($f3) {
    $f3->set('html_title', 'MyServer');
    $f3->set('content', 'index.html');
    echo Template::instance()->render('layout.php');
  }
```

Comment: Is PHP actually running on _your server_?

Comment: Your ```$SESSION``` should be ```$_SESSION```. And should be ```$_SESSION['userName']```

Comment: I can see that $SESSION.userName output so it should be running.

Comment: Try a PHP file with only this content: `<?php phpinfo();` It should produce a long page with information about your PHP. Does it?

Comment: Does your file have a .html or a .php extension?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, it gave me a big list of information, the PHP version is 7.4.28. I am using a server that I am sure that PHP is inststalled and configured on it.

Comment: @NigelRen It has html extension.

Comment: Ah, well, normally you would need to use the php extension for PHP files.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware This is php embedded into html

Comment: I understand, but just try to change the extension from .html to .php and see if that helps... it probably will. Only .php files are scanned for embedded PHP code (normally).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Did that but no difference.

Comment: Let me check whether the syntax you used, which is rather obscure, is still valid in PHP 7.4.28.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware This document says that it is valid: https://www.php.net/control-structures.alternative-syntax

Comment: Yes, just found that as well.

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of ideas. PHP works, you use the .php extension, and your syntax is valid. You could still check the PHP logs, to see if anything is there, but I doubt it.

Comment: how to check php logs?

Comment: The `<?php phpinfo();` will probably tell you where they are located. They are normal text file, but the location can vary. Alternatively, you could [show the errors in the HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display).

Comment: You're mixing up PHP code with some templating language understood by `Template::instance()->render()`. The parts that *are* working are the non-PHP parts like `{{ @SESSION.userName }}`. You need to look up the proper syntax for if statements in that templating language, not native PHP.

Comment: I have something like that on my site but it uses  `if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {` then redirect user back to index.php if they are not logged in

Comment: So use `<?php if($_SESSION['username']=='UNSET'):  ?>`

Comment: @IMSoP I am using F3 library for templating and other tasks.

Comment: Then you need to learn the syntax it uses for if statements, not mix in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using f3 template engine, according to its [documentation](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.7/views-and-templates#ConditionalSegments) you can use this for your condition:

```
<check if="{{ @SESSION.userName=='UNSET' }}">
    <true>
        <div>User is not logged in</div>
    </true>
    <false>
        <div> user is logged in: user name is: {{ @SESSION.userName }}</div>
    </false>
</check>
```